# Determining $(a\times(a\times(a\times(a\times b))))$ for vectors $a$ and $b$, where $|a|=2$, $|b|=3$, $a\cdot b=0$

Tags: vectors, inner-products

> If $|a|=2$ and $|b|=3$ and $a\cdot b=0$, then determine
> $$( 
> a\times( 
> a\times( 
> a\times( 
> a\times
> b))))$$
> where $a$ and $b$ are vectors.

What I am doing wrong here?

We know

$$|a\times b|^2 + |a\cdot b|^2 = |a|^2|b|^2$$ where $\times$ is the cross product and $\cdot$ is the dot product.

Then after simplification
$$(a\times b) = 6$$

Then I can put $(a\times b) = 6$ at the end of the question and the question will be
$$a\times( 
a\times( 
a\times( 
6))))$$

Isn't the answer not equal to $0$ as $a\times a =0$.

Where I am wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... You're confusing vector products with arithmetical ones. Note that the identity you provide should read $$|a\times b|^2+|a\cdot b|^2=|a|^2|b|^2$$ as it is an *arithmetical* relation involving *lengths* of the vectors involved. Also, $a\times b$ is not $6$; rather, $|a|\,|b|=6$, whereas $a\times b$ is *a particular vector orthogonal to $a$ and $b$*. Calling that vector $c$, then $a\times c$ is *a particular vector orthogonal to $a$ and $c$*; since $a$ and $b$ are themselves orthogonal (why?), this new vector must be parallel to $b$. Can you continue?

Comment: It would also be nice to learn MathJax.  Basic stuff is very easy and it makes things much clearer and prettier.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Blue that is a typo I do realize after reading your comment thanks. And I would say ∣axb∣=6 not (axb).

Comment: @Ankit: Typos are understandable. Indeed, I made one myself. I *meant* to write $$|a\times b|^2+(a\cdot b)^2=|a|^2|b|^2$$ where "$|\;\;|$" is understood to be the *vector norm*. Writing $|a\cdot b|^2$ isn't *technically* incorrect —provided "$|\;\;|$" is interpreted for that term as the arithmetical *absolute value* (as $a\cdot b$ is a scalar)— but in a comment drawing a distinction between vectorial and arithmetical operations, doing so is unnecessarily confusing (and just-plain *unnecessary*, since $|x|^2=x^2$).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the triple product in this exercise

$$u\times (v\times w)=(u\cdot w)\,v-(u\cdot v)\,w$$

Applying for $u=v=a$ and $w=b$ you get

$a\times (a\times b)=\underbrace{(a\cdot b)}_0\,a-\underbrace{(a\cdot a)}_{|a|^2}\,b=-4\,b$

And you can iterate the processus since you now have $a\times (a\times (-4b))=(-4)^2\,b=16\,b$